# Kullback-Leibler divergence between Standard Gaussian Distribution and Standard Cauchy distribution

Tags: calculus, probability

Is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between Standard Gaussian Distribution given by

$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{(-\frac{x^2}{2})}$

and the standard Cauchy distribution given by

$g(x) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} $ finite?

Answer (score 3):

If $P$ is a standard Gaussian variable and $Q$ is a standard Cauchy variable, then:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}D_{KL}(P|Q)&=&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\log\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}}{\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}}\,dx\\&=&\log\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\log(1+x^2)\right)e^{-x^2/2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
is obviously finite since
$$-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq-\frac{x^2}{2}+\log(1+x^2)\leq \frac{x^2}{2}, $$
so:
$$ 0\leq D_{KL}(P|Q) \leq  \log\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[P^2]=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+\log\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}.$$
Obviously $D_{KL}(Q|P)$ **is not** finite, since $\mathbb{E}[Q^2]$ is not finite.