# Conditions for existence of KL divergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am interested in understanding when the KL divergence exists between two distributions $P$ and $Q$. Recall that this quantity is defined as

$$
D_{KL}(P|Q) := \int \log \frac{dP}{dQ} \, dP.
$$

In general, we always require $P \ll Q$ for this definition to make sense, but it seems that we also need $\log dP/dQ \in L^1(P)$, and so my question is essentially whether there exist useful conditions on $P$ and $Q$ that are sufficient to ensure this holds.

For simplicity, let's assume $P \ll Q \ll \mu$ for some $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, so that

$$
D_{KL}(P|Q) = \int \log \frac{p}{q} \, dP = \int \log p - \log q \, dP
$$

where $p$ and $q$ are respectively the densities of $P$ and $Q$ with respect to $\mu$. It seems therefore what we want to characterise are conditions for

$$ \tag{*} \label{*}
\log p, \log q \in L^1(P).
$$

There are examples for which this doesn't hold: e.g., when P is a standard Cauchy distribution and Q is a standard Gaussian, then $\log p \in L^1(P)$ but $\log q \notin L^1(P)$, so $D_{KL}(P|Q)$ does not exist - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098852/kullback-leibler-divergence-between-standard-gaussian-distribution-and-standard). However, do certain assumptions about $P$ and $Q$ guarantee \eqref{*}?

I would also be interested to hear answers to the following:

- Is it possible to have $\log p \notin L^1(P)$ and $\log q \in L^1(P)$?
- Is it possible to have $\log p, \log q \notin L^1(P)$, but $\log p - \log q \in L^1(P)$?